# Is there a connection between how casting is done and concept of polymorphic behaviour

Tags: java, c++, actionscript-3, oop

Is there a connection between how casting is done and the concept of polymorphic behaviour?

Comment: In Java, C++, ActionScript 3, or C (which, incidentally, doesn't support inheritance)?  The answer is quite possibly different for each of these languages.

Answer (score 1):

Specific to C++, casting is used sometimes like this:

```
void TestFunction(BaseClass* base_class_object)
{
    DerivedClass* d = dynamic_cast<DerivedClass*>(base_class_object); 
    d->method(); 
}
```

Assuming that `BaseClass` is declared as polymorphic (i.e., it has a `virtual` method), the `dynamic_cast` will correctly cast the `base_class_object` if it points to a full `DerivedClass` object. IIRC, it will return a null pointer otherwise. Thus during runtime, you can dynamically determine the type of an object and do more stuff with it, with the help of 'casting'.

---

Update -

Tony's response, and the comment by Als, both nicely supplement my response and provide a fuller picture.

Comment: Adding to the above to specifically answer the Q, dynamic_cast works only with polymorphic classes, while static_cast can work on non polymorphic classes, So that is the relation.

Answer (score 1):

In C++, an object may inherit from multiple base classes, in which case there will typically be an independent and contiguous area of memory inside the object that follows the memory layout of each base.  This makes it easy for the compiler to pass a pointer/reference to a "base class" sub-component should the derived object be used as an argument to a function expecting the base class.  static_cast and dynamic_cast similarly choose the particular part of a subject to point to based on the cast-to type, though dynamic_cast goes further and performs limited run-time verification of the validity of cast, returning 0 if given a pointer to a different-from-asked derived class.  reinterpret cast doesn't have any special support for finding particular base objects when given a pointer to a derived object, and doesn't adjust or validate the pointer.  Summarily, it's quite true to say that some of C++'s casting and polymorphism features need to work cooperatively.